# What do ActionResultObjectValueAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-core

In the [ActionResultObjectValueAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.actionresultobjectvalueattribute) documentation :

> Attribute annotated on ActionResult constructor, helper method parameters, and properties to indicate that the parameter or property is used to set the "value" for ActionResult.
>
> Analyzers match this parameter by type name. This allows users to annotate custom results \ custom helpers with a user-defined attribute without having to expose this type.

I see this attribute is used to parameter in constructor in many derived classes from [ObjectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult). For example, the [BadRequestObjectResult's constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/57c3104f0d19bb9e25b8ba75b422e2d6072e1dd5/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/BadRequestObjectResult.cs#L22) :

```cs
public BadRequestObjectResult([ActionResultObjectValue] object? error)
```

And it is used to parameter in ControllerBase's result methods, like [ControllerBase.BadRequest](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/57c3104f0d19bb9e25b8ba75b422e2d6072e1dd5/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/BadRequestObjectResult.cs#L22)

```cs
public virtual BadRequestObjectResult BadRequest([ActionResultObjectValue] object? error)
```

What is ActionResultObjectValueAttribute for?

Comment: Lets assume that we want to call IActionResult in one controller from another controller. It could be possible that sometimes you will not receive valid response from that controller and it will crash the app. In that situation, we could use `ActionResultObjectValue` to set the specific status code or error message.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, this explains why when an enumeration crashes, the status code is maintained.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, sorry, I mixed `ActionResultObjectValueAttribute` and `ActionResultObjectValue` in my question. It's fixed.